# How many presidents have been subject to a grand jury?

Tags: united-states, president

I can't find a source that tells me how many Presidents have been involved in a grand jury investigation. Help?

Comment: Do you mean while president, before or after? Not that many presidents actually committed crimes and impeachment would be the method to be used while president.

Comment: @sabbahillel I rather suspect that many presidents committed crimes, but that the crimes did not in most cases become common knowledge.

Comment: @phoog I suspect that it was the 20th century that this would apply to. However, none were caught.

Comment: Not sure why the downvotes. Perhaps a bit trivial, but I think it's an interesting question. Nixon went before a Grand Jury. Clinton as well. But I'm not sure if any others have.

Answer (score 6):

Assuming we are talking about US presidents, two of them are documented:

- Richard Nixon in 1974
- Bill Clinton in 1998

https://www.theguardian.com/us-news/2017/aug/04/what-is-a-grand-jury-and-how-serious-is-it-for-donald-trump

It seems that although Andrew Johnson faced impeachment in 1868, he wasn't subject to a grand jury.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Andrew_Johnson

(Sorry for my previous erroneous statement about A.Johnson)

Comment: Can you link to your sources ? That would show it is an exhaustive list ?